# Meaning of starting d and starting l in drwxr-xr-x and lrwxr-xr-x

Tags: ls, acl

There are two files with the permission strings `drwxr-xr-x` and  `lrwxr-xr-x`.

I was wondering what the starting `d` and starting `l` stand for?

Comment: The ACL indicator is the character *after* the file permissions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the question.

Comment: Detailed information at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html (assuming your OS uses GNU tools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `d` stands for directory.  The `l` stands for symbolic link.

The first character in the permissions string has nothing to do with permissions.  It simply identifies what kind of object it is.

Comment: Shouldn't "object" be replaced with "file" since everything in Linux is a file? Good answer though.

Comment: Meh. Semantics I suppose. If we *really* wanted to be pedantic we'd call them "nodes" :-)  Linux is kind of inconsistent. If you `cp` or `mv` a link with no arguments, it copies the link itself, not the thing it references. But if you tried to `cp` or `mv` a device node (i.e. in the `/dev` directory), it would copy the thing it references, not the node itself. Internally the filesystem uses "nodes" to reference everything. You can treat everything as though it were a "file". But to a programmer, everything (including memory) is an object of some kind. So I guess it just depends on context.

Comment: Touché about "nodes" and you're right about everything being considered an object of some type.

Answer (score 0):

"d" means the file is a directory  (folder)

"l" means the file is symbolic link (shortcut)

Comment: Did you read the answer above? @Wes Sayeed already gave the (same) answer!

Comment: Oh. Anyway, I felt like proving my own two cents since I've dabbling with *nix OSes. Sheesh! ;-)